# question about .Contains()

Tags: apex, string, text, contains

I have a quick question in regards to using `.Contains()`. I'm writing an if statement and need to update a text field if it contains "VA". However, if it contains "IVA" it shouldn't update this field. What would be the best way to make sure I capture anything with "VA" except for "IVA"?

Comment: what if text looks like `abcVALUE`  -- match or no match?

Comment: match. it just cannot be `iVALUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with regex but a simple solution is:

```
if (myString.contains('VA') && !myString.contains('IVA')) {
    ... do field update
 }
```

Comment: thank you! knew it was something simple but couldn't figure it out lol